# Dockerised Google Cloud Storage for sandboxed environments

Tags: docker, google-cloud-storage, minio

Can anyone recomend a good docker service that I can use in place of Google Cloud Storage in a sandboxed environment.

Previously when using AWS, I have swapped out the S3 buckets for a minio server running in a docker container as it has the same APIs. I'm looking for something similar

Thanks

Comment: If I may ask ... what's the high level thinking here?  Are you looking for a self-contained service that implements the APIs and semantics of GCS?

Comment: @Kolban basicly yeah. It's for sandboxed dev environments and testing